# Why am I getting a com.stormpath.sdk.lang.InstantiationException while trying to get an OAuth2 key from Stormpath?

Tags: java, gradle, jersey, stormpath

I'm building a Java REST API, using Jersey. Tomcat is my web server. For user account and OAuth2 key management, I'm using Stormpath's Java SDK. I have one sample user already created through the website, and every time I post a JSON username/password request for that account to my app's `v1/token` endpoint in Postman, I get this exception and stacktrace:

```
com.stormpath.sdk.lang.InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate instance with constructor [public com.stormpath.sdk.impl.oauth.DefaultAccessToken(com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.InternalDataStore,java.util.Map)]
    at com.stormpath.sdk.lang.Classes.instantiate(Classes.java:191)
    at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultResourceFactory.instantiate(DefaultResourceFactory.java:65)
    at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore.instantiate(DefaultDataStore.java:170)
    at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.oauth.DefaultGrantAuthenticationToken.getAsAccessToken(DefaultGrantAuthenticationToken.java:79)
    at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.oauth.DefaultOauthGrantAuthenticationResultBuilder.build(DefaultOauthGrantAuthenticationResultBuilder.java:87)
    at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.oauth.DefaultOauthGrantAuthenticationResultBuilder.build(DefaultOauthGrantAuthenticationResultBuilder.java:24)
    at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.oauth.DefaultPasswordGrantAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultPasswordGrantAuthenticator.java:56)
    at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.oauth.DefaultPasswordGrantAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultPasswordGrantAuthenticator.java:28)
    at com.ficcy.api.services.AuthService.getToken(AuthService.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.stormpath.sdk.lang.Classes.instantiate(Classes.java:188)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: io.jsonwebtoken.JwtException: JWT failed validation; it cannot be trusted.
    at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.oauth.DefaultAccessToken.ensureAccessToken(DefaultAccessToken.java:56)
    at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.oauth.DefaultAccessToken.<init>(DefaultAccessToken.java:35)
    ... 59 more
```

My JSON:

```
{
    "login": "**EMAIL**",
    "password": "**PASSWORD**"
}
```

There wasn't anything in the docs for the [exception](http://docs.stormpath.com/java/apidocs/index.html?com/stormpath/sdk/lang/class-use/InstantiationException.html). This is my endpoint/service. (I started catching any and all exceptions just so I could take a look at what was happening. also, AuthRequest is a simple bean with not null constraints on the login and password fields):

```
package com.ficcy.api.services;
//truncated imports

@Path("/token")
public class AuthService {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public AccessToken getToken(AuthRequest ar) {

        AccessToken rtn = null;

        try {

            PasswordGrantRequest pgr = Oauth2Requests.PASSWORD_GRANT_REQUEST.builder().setLogin(ar.getLogin())
                    .setPassword(ar.getPassword()).build();

            OauthGrantAuthenticationResult authResult = Authenticators.PASSWORD_GRANT_AUTHENTICATOR
                    .forApplication(Config.getApplication()).authenticate(pgr);
            rtn = authResult.getAccessToken();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rtn;
    }

}
```

EDIT: Here's my Config class, where I store my Stormpath Application:

```
package com.ficcy.api.config;
//truncated imports

public class Config {
    private static Client client = Clients.builder().build();
    private static Application application;

    static {

        Tenant tenant = client.getCurrentTenant();
        ApplicationList applications = tenant
                .getApplications(Applications.where(Applications.name().eqIgnoreCase("ficcy-api")));

        application = applications.iterator().next();

    }

    public static Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public static Application getApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    public static Hashids getHashid(String salt) {
        return new Hashids(salt, 6);
    }

}
```

And build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/akhikhl/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'

dependencies {

    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.22.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:2.22.1'  
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.22.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.22.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.security:oauth1-client:2.22.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.22.1'

    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38'

    compile 'com.stormpath.sdk:stormpath-sdk-api:1.0.RC8.3'

    compile 'junit:junit-dep:4.+'    
    compile 'org.hashids:hashids:1.0.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit-dep:4.+'

    runtime 'com.stormpath.sdk:stormpath-sdk-impl:1.0.RC8.3'
    runtime 'com.stormpath.sdk:stormpath-sdk-httpclient:1.0.RC8.3'

    }

gretty {
    port = 8080
    servletContainer = 'tomcat8'
    fastReload = true
    contextPath = '/'
    httpsEnabled = true

}
```

Comment: Are you using Java SDK version `1.0.RC8.3`? At which exact line in your code are you getting the exception? I have not being able to reproduce your error when executing the code you showed in `AuthService#getToken(AuthRequest)`

Comment: I am using Java 8 `1.0.66`. I changed my build.gradle to use `1.0.RC8.2` vs `1.0.RC8.3` for all Stormpath libraries a few minutes before I saw you responded, and everything worked. I just switched back to `1.0.RC8.3`, and it's failing again. EDIT: The error is on line 33.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are getting that error when creating the `access_token`? I have the suspicion that you are basically trying to authenticate an erroneous `access_token`. Could you try re-creating it and then re-executing the piece of code that is throwing the Exception but this time with the newly generated `access_token`?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, it's throwing the error on 33, here: 

OauthGrantAuthenticationResult authResult = Authenticators.PASSWORD_GRANT_AUTHENTICATOR
                    .forApplication(Config.getApplication()).authenticate(pgr);'

Comment: When I compile with `1.0.RC8.2` instead of `1.0.RC8.3`, everything works exactly as expected. The line quoted above fails when I use `1.0.RC8.3`.

Comment: In `1.0.RC8.3` the whole token management approach changed. I am sure you are using an old token. Things should work fine if you create a new access_token.

Comment: Every time I POST a login/password JSON object (represented by AuthRequest) to my endpoint and all goes well, I get a new access_token. Is that what you mean? Also, I've been using [Stormpath's OAuth 2.0 Token management guides](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/token-management/). Where can I find info about the new token management approach?

Comment: Yes, simply use this new `access_token` and it will work. You can read about the new Token Management here: https://docs.stormpath.com/guides/token-management/. You can see how this was integrated into our Spring Stack here: https://docs.stormpath.com/java/spring-boot-web/tutorial.html#token-management

Comment: Will keep an eye out for when the new approach rolls out for the Java SDK. In the meantime, I'll use `1.0.RC8.2` and the flow I have working, and refactor when the time comes.

Comment: Feel free to submit a request to https://support.stormpath.com so your issue can be discussed and solved.

Comment: I have the same problem in RC8.6. The returned token OauthGrantAuthenticationResult can not return me the account via oauthGrantAuthenticationResult.getAccessToken().getAccount(); Similarly, rolling back to 8.2 resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Stormpath SDK, access token fails validation when you set refresh tokens expiration (time to live) to 0, i.e. you don't want to issue them. This causes rti claims in JWT to be nil and fails access token validation. Quick fix if to set refresh token ttl to something else than 0. I'll report the bug to Stormpath.